How to give custom name to post handler in Razor Pages?
I'm implementing Stripe payments on my website.
They say to create the following method on my page.
[HttpPost("create-checkout-session")]
public ActionResult CreateCheckoutSession()
{
    // ...
}

However, this is MVC syntax and I'm using Razor Pages.
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    // ...
}

I know how to use named handlers, but I don't know how to give my method the name create-checkout-session.

in razor your controller name would = the route.  Method used is based on OnPost, OnPostAsync, or OnGet, OnGetAsync.  (use the async methods).  So one controller = two methods... one for post and one for get, but you don't necessarily need to have two.  So you'd have public class CreateCheckoutSessionModel: PageModel {....   where route would be to name of the the files, i.e.  CreateCheckoutSession.cshtml, and CreateCheckoutSession.cshtml.cs.

So above URL would be: yourdomain . com / CreateCheckoutSession That should be default mapping, but you can configure it in different ways if you like.   The controller will always return a Page, from PageModel... (after processing the .cshtml file)  though you could also redirect to another controller that would then return the Page.

The name create-checkout-session is just a recommendation, not a requirement.  The main thing you need to do is have your frontend code call a route on your server that will create a Checkout Session and then perform the next required steps, which vary depending on how exactly you're integrating Stripe.

Okay, I see. Thanks. BTW, the call still seems to be failing. I'm using the code from Stripe's website. Do you think this is related to forgery tokens?

@JonathanWood If you are posting from the client using FETCH or an AJAX library, fail to include the request verification token in the payload and get a 400 status code, then it is highly likely to be a missing forgery token issue.
